I have started setting up reCAPTCHA v3 on my website's JavaScript code and have a question
I am following the integration guide from Google on my website and am attaching the reCAPTCHA to the "submit" button on a Contact Us form.  This is to hopefully reduce the amount of SPAM bots from contacting my business with irrelevant messages.
Here is the code I have added to the head tag for the Contact page:
<script>
        function onSubmitForm(token) {
    document.getElementById("contact").submit();
}
      </script>

The initialization guide on Google has this for attaching the reCAPTCHA to a button element:
<!-- Replace the variables below. -->
<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
  }
</script>

What are these variables?  I looked at the other tab for attaching to a user interaction (Login) and this is what will be executed:
<script>
  function onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
      const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('6LcuEMspAAAAABuu38RUpLBx6ntP-J5XcAU1CHHm', {action: 'LOGIN'});
    });
  }
</script>

Do I use some of the function from the user interaction integration on the function that's attaching the reCAPTCHA to the form button?  Like adding the const token line to the onSubmit function?
Edit May 1, 2024
Here is the HTML form I have added to the webpage:
<form class="contact" name="contact" id="reCAPTCHAform" action="mailto:emailaddresshere" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Contact Home Sewn Treasures</legend>
              <label>First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="50" /><br />
              <br />
              <label>Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="50" /><br />
              <br />
              <label>E-Mail Address*</label>
              <input type="email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" size="50" required /><br />
              <br />
              <label>Subject</label>
              <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="50" /><br />
              <br />
              <label>Message*</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="yourMessage" size="150" required></textarea><br />
              <input class="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
              <button class="g-reCAPTCHA" id="submit" data-sitekey="6LcuEMspAAAAABuu38RUpLBx6ntP-J5XcAU1CHHm" data-callback="onSubmitForm" data-action="submit" onclick="return changeCursor();">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
          </form>


The "variables" aren't actually variables, but CSS selectors that reference your form. So in your first code block, it assumes your form has id attribute, e.g. <form id='contact'>...</form>. The second block expects <form id='demo-form'>..</form>.  The 3rd code block is an alternate way of implementing reCaptcha if you want more control over it. For example, reading the returned score and having your site behave differently based on the returned score.

Post what the html of your form looks like and I can give more specific example of what you should do.

I just saw the edits this morning, the e-mail address that you edited out is the e-mail address for my business, but not sure if I need to change it to the e-mail address for the Google account the reCAPTCHA is set up with.

I do not see anything relevant to the email address in google's reCapcha docs. I assume whoever edited out your email was just trying to be helpful in case you didn't mean to broadcast your email publicly (wasn't me).

Okay, based on your posted form code, you have id="reCAPTCHAform" and data-callback="onSubmitForm", so overall, you should

make sure you have the google recaptcha script tag included on your site:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

Based on what you have in your <form>...</form> markup, you should also include the following on your page:


    <script>
    function onSubmitForm(token) {            
        document.getElementById("reCAPTCHAform").submit();
    }
    </script>

Note: You listed 3 different functions in your original post. You only need one (the one I just posted here).

In your form's button element,change your class="g-reCAPTCHA" to class="g-recaptcha" (it's case-sensitive)

<button class="g-recaptcha" id="submit" data-sitekey="6LcuEMspAAAAABuu38RUpLBx6ntP-J5XcAU1CHHm" data-callback="onSubmitForm" data-action="submit" onclick="return changeCursor();">Submit</button>


Also in your form's button element, you have onclick="return changeCursor();"  This may or may not block google's recaptcha stuff, depending on what that changeCursor() function actually does. You didn't post any info about it, though. So if you still don't see recaptcha stuff working after previous changes, try removing that onclick attribute first, to remove that from the equation.


Thanks, that really helped.  The change cursor works by changing the cursor when the user hovers over the "submit" button while the form is submitting.
